# Public static assets in module folders?

Tags: meteor, directory-structure

I want to organize my Meteor app in modules, i.e. having a folder for each specific section or functionality of my app containing all related files.

This would preferably also include static assets such as images but the special `public/` folder only seems to work in the project root.

Or am I missing something?

For my project, it feels like overkill (less clean, even) having the overhead of creating a proper package for every little module of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to do it is to use a package. You can add static assets to a package, and the file can be accessed with the URL: `/packages/[package name]/[path to file]`. Here's an example of a `package.js` for [hopscotch](https://github.com/linkedin/hopscotch):

```js
Package.describe({
  summary: 'A framework to make it easy for developers to add product tours.'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.0.0');
  api.addFiles('img/sprite-green.png', 'client');
  api.addFiles('img/sprite-orange.png', 'client');
  api.addFiles('css/hopscotch.css', 'client');
  api.addFiles('js/hopscotch.js', 'client');
});
```

As you can see, all of the images are under the `img` directory within the package. To access the `sprite-green.png` file, I would use `/packages/hopscotch/img/sprite-green.png`.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, although I may create a package or two, I prefer having my static assets in `/public` for most of my modules, rather than updating a lot of `package.js` files. It makes my project easier for other developers to read.